# for i in `./script `cat file`` syntax

Tags: bash, for-loop, parameters, cat, seq

I have a script which uses parameters. In the shell I run the script like this: `./script 1 2 3 4`. I prefer to use a file which contain 1 2 3 4 in a single line and run: `` ./script `cat file` ``.

After I call this script in a for loop like this: `` for i in `./script `cat file` ` `` but it doesn't work. What is the good syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest tilde (command substitution) like this. You can do this bash:

```
for i in $(./script $(<file))
```

`$(<file)` is another way of getting the output of `$(cat file)`

Answer (score 4):

Use `$()` instead of `\``` for Command Substitution. This, among other things, is one of the many reasons it is better.

That being said using `cat file` to get a list of words is, at best, a poor idea and, at worst, a broken (and potentially dangerous) one. It will not work with any words that require spaces or use shell globbing characters.

I suggest not doing it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

```
man seq
```

generate a sequence of numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
  echo $i
done
```